# Software for autocompletetion (bash/zsh) using IA

Tags: linux, machine-learning, bash, shell-scripting, autocomplete

Is there any software for autocompletion in the console (bash, zsh) that uses some AI?

I know how to autocomplete in bash and zsh (*autoload*, *compgen*, etc), but I want something more "smart", not only using the common autocompletion, or the command-line history (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>), or `history | grep ...`.

Recently I tried GitHub Copilot autocompletion for coding and I liked it, so I was wondering if there is a similar feature or project for *bash/zsh*.

Of course, I've searched on google, but I have not found such a thing.

Comment: On macOS there is Warp (https://www.warp.dev/). They plan to release also a Linux and Windows version (https://www.warp.dev/faq#is-there-a-timeline-for-linux-and-windows).

Comment: Without AI (ATM), but helps if you need to auto-complete for large systems with domain-specific keywords: https://github.com/uvsmtid/argrelay

Comment: https://github.com/tom-doerr/zsh_codex is in that direction but not quite an autosuggest